# How can I design gmail send with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am implementing client mail. I want to send mail to multiple receipients like gmail.

How can I create that view with two input fields in a text box sharing a close button?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are called chips and you can find a tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_chips.asp.

Comment: thank u sir one another thing is how can i put that div into text box?

Comment: You can start with tagsinput: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tagsinput

Comment: http://jsbin.com/facelehixi

Comment: Thanks to all ...but at last i found my expected solution with bootstrap tokenfield http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged jQuery and Bootstrap in your question. So here is [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) - a jQuery plugin providing a Twitter Bootstrap user interface for managing tags.

If you want autocompletion functionality, it also works with [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) - a flexible JavaScript library that provides a strong foundation for building robust typeaheads (autocompletion).

Comment: Thanks to all ...but at last i found my expected solution with bootstrap tokenfield http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/